# What is the past tense of the verb "bode"?

Tags: conjugation

I refer to the verb ***bode***, meaning "to be a portent of a particular outcome" as in a sentence such as *her success bodes well for the future*.

Most often I see the past in the form of *her success in London 2012 did bode well for Rio 2016*.

But I cannot find a past form of *boded* in any dictionary, including the OED. Does it exist?

Comment: Surely AHDEL should have been checked?

Comment: What is AHDEL? Google seems never to have heard of it.

Comment: [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boded): << **bode** 1 ...
**v.** boded, boding, bodes
**v.tr.**
1. To be an omen of: heavy seas that boded trouble for small craft.
2. Archaic To predict; foretell. //
**v.intr.**
To be an omen; portend: The peace accord bodes well for the city under siege.>> // Not having convenient access to the OED, I _start_ a search with the _Free Dictionary_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the helpful link. [Oldham Library](http://www.oldham.gov.uk/info/200284/online_reference_library) gives you free online access to "dictionaries, encyclopaedias, and online reference books".

Comment: And if it is like my local library you can gain access from your own computer log-in at home.

Comment: It's boded I know, but I hereby stump for "bood"

Answer (score 4):

***Boded*** seems fine to me - "Her success boded well for the future.

I guess that '*boded*' often does not come up in the description of the verb because it is 'regular'...

The OED provides a couple of rather ancient examples (most of their examples use present tense).

1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden Polychron. (1865) II. 293   It ***bodid*** grete merite and vertue.

1676   Dryden Aureng-Zebe ii. 26   What ever now The omen prove, it ***boded*** well to you.
▸a1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden Polychron. (St. John's Cambr.)

Comment: +1 Parallel tracks! -- If you want to appropriate the Bosworth-Toller/OE part, I'll concede your priority and delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to have been a weak verb all the way back to OE *bodian* (alternatively *bodigan*, *bodigean*): [Bosworth-Toller](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/004799) gives the preterite suffixes in various spellings as *ode, -ede, -ade, -ude* (and past participle suffixes as *-od, -ed, -ad, -ud*—I've added all those hyphens to BT's notation). Some examples cited in [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/960/mode/2up):

> **bododon** englas ðæt acenned wæs Crist on eorþan —***Boded** angels that born was Christ on earth* = "Angels announced that Christ was born on earth" —*Hymns*, ca. 1000
>
> It **bodid** grete merite and vertue —John of Trevisa, transl. Ranulf Higden's *Polychronicon*, 1387
>
> Whatever now The omen proved, It **boded** well to you —Dryden, *Aurung-Zebe*, 1675

Answer (score 1):

Both Merriam-Webster and American Heritage dictionaries online show **boded** as the past tense form of **bode**.  From AHD:

> bode 1  (bōd)
>
> Share:   v. bod·ed, bod·ing, bodes v.tr.
>   1. To be an omen of: heavy seas that boded trouble for small craft.
>   2. Archaic To predict; foretell. v.intr. To be an omen; portend: The peace accord bodes well for the city under siege.

From M-W:

> Full Definition of bode
>
> boded boding
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 archaic :  to announce beforehand :  foretell
>
> 2 :  to indicate by signs :  presage

Comment: Beat me by seconds +1